# Unduplicated random Numbers in an java array

Tags: java, arrays

I've searched and simply cannot find an answer to my problem.
I have to create a lotto type simulation, 6 numbers + bonus number with no duplicates.
i have manged to get it working but in the 6 number array the number at poistion [1] comes out as 0 all the time.I'm sure its simple issue but I'm brand new to this so any help will be gratefully accepted.Code below, I'm sure its all over the place........

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lotto {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] Lotto=new int[6];
        final int MIN = 1;
        final int MAX = 45;

        for (int i = 0; i< Lotto.length; ++i)
        {

            Lotto [0] =MIN+ (int)(Math.random()*((MAX -MIN)+1));

            while (Lotto[1] == Lotto[0])
            {
                Lotto[1] =MIN+ (int)(Math.random()*((MAX -MIN)+1));
            }

            while ((Lotto[2] == Lotto[0]) || (Lotto[2] == Lotto[1]) )
            {
                Lotto[2] = MIN+ (int)(Math.random()*((MAX -MIN)+1));

            while ((Lotto[3] == Lotto[0]) || (Lotto[3] == Lotto[1]) || (Lotto[3] == Lotto[2]) )
            {
                Lotto[3] = MIN+ (int)(Math.random()*((MAX -MIN)+1));
            }

            while  ((Lotto[4] == Lotto[0]) || (Lotto[4] == Lotto[1]) || (Lotto[4] == Lotto[2]) ||   (Lotto[4] == Lotto[3]) )                        

            {
                Lotto[4] = MIN+ (int)(Math.random()*((MAX -MIN)+1));



                while  ((Lotto[5] == Lotto[0]) || (Lotto[5] == Lotto[1]) || (Lotto[5] == Lotto[2]) ||   (Lotto[5] == Lotto[3])||    (Lotto[5] == Lotto[4])) 

                {
                    Lotto[5] = MIN+ (int)(Math.random()*((MAX -MIN)+1));
                }


                int[] BonusNumber=new int[1];
                for (int j = 0; j< BonusNumber.length; ++j)
                {

                    BonusNumber [j] =1+ (int)(Math.random()*((45 -1)+1));
                }

                System.out.println("Winner  "  + Arrays.toString(Lotto));
                System.out.println("Bonus Number" +Arrays.toString(BonusNumber));   
            {


    }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Change this loop:

```
while (Lotto[1] == Lotto[0])
{
    Lotto[1] = random(MIN, MAX);
}
```

into:

```
do {
    Lotto[1] = random(MIN, MAX);
} while (Lotto[1] == Lotto[0]);
```

And the rest of the code accordingly. Do you see where the problem lies?

But before you start rewriting your quite complex and unmaintainable code, check out this implementation, that is much easier to understand and... correct:

```
final int MIN = 1;
final int MAX = 45;

final List<Integer> allPossible = new ArrayList<Integer>(MAX - MIN + 1);
for (int i = MIN; i <= MAX; ++i) {
    allPossible.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(allPossible);
final List<Integer> lotto = allPossible.subList(0, 6);
int bonusNumber = allPossible.get(6);

System.out.println("Winner  "     + lotto);
System.out.println("Bonus Number" + bonusNumber);
```

[`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) is crucial here.

Comment: Tomasz,many thanks, i see it now.unmaintainable it might be ,but i have to stick to my course text,we have not covered Collections,so i cant use it,seems daft but thats the way they want it,only 2 months into this so im sure we'll cover it all.

Answer (score 3):

I think your code is quite confusing and you can avoid so much conditions by using some API utilities such as `Collections.shuffle()` as in this example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Integer[] numbers = new Integer[45];

    // Populating numbers.
    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)
        numbers[i] = i + 1;

    // Shuffling them to make them in random order.
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
    Collections.shuffle(list);

    // Print any 6 of them. I chose first 6 ones for simplicity.
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
}
```

**Sample output:**

```
15 11 31 2 5 38
```

Comment: You have an off-by-one error, OP wants values from `1` to `45`, you are returning from `0` to `44`.

Comment: No problem. However may I suggest simply iterating from `1` to `<= 45` to avoid 45 `+1` operations? Microoptimization, but an easy win.

Comment: @DelShekasteh.. Please don't ask people to upvote your answers. They would themselves do that for deserving answers. Just an advice. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashSet` which keeps neither order nor duplicates.

You can also make a new instance of the `java.util.Random` class every time you need a new random number as this changes the seed and will give your application more randomness, eliminating position 1 containing 0 every time.

`new java.util.Random().nextInt(int max)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an int[] and not the built in classes you can do

```
int[] ints = new int[45];
for (int i = 0; i < ints.length; i++) ints[i] = i + 1;
Random rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    int swap = rand.nextInt(ints.length - i) + i;
    int tmp = ints[i];
    ints[i] = ints[swap];
    ints[swap] = tmp;
}
int[] drawn = Arrays.copyOf(ints, 6);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(drawn));
```

prints

```
[19, 22, 24, 6, 34, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm taking the same intro Java class as you (as that program looks eerily familiar) so I'll try to keep it to just the basic stuff; I did however copy all of the original code from your program, so you did basically all the work, I just cleaned it up a bit.

This is the complete program (randomizes a set of numbers (checking for repeats), allows a user to choose a set or randomize their own (also checking for repeats), sorts and compares the two sets, informs the user if they won or not, asks to play again:

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Lotto
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        boolean checkPlay = false, readInput = false;
        final int MAX = 45;

        while (readInput != true)
        {
            System.out.print("Would you like to buy a lotto ticket? [y/n] ");
            String stBuyTicket = keyboard.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

            if (stBuyTicket.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
            }
            else if (stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'y' || stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'n')
            {
                if (stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'y')
                {
                    checkPlay = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    checkPlay = false;                    
                }
                readInput = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
            }
        }        
        while (checkPlay == true)
        { 
            int[] lotto = new int[6];
            int lottoLength = lotto.length;
            int[] userLotto = new int[6];
            int userLottoLength = userLotto.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < lottoLength; i++)
            {
                boolean checkLotto = false;
                while (checkLotto != true)
                {  
                    int numCheck = (rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1);
                    boolean confirmSame = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                    {
                        if (numCheck == lotto[j])
                        {
                            confirmSame = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (confirmSame != true)
                    {
                        lotto[i] = numCheck;
                        checkLotto = true;                                               
                    }
                }
            }            
            readInput = false;
            while (readInput != true)
            {
                System.out.println("Would you like choose your own numbers or just randomize them?");
                System.out.print("Choose your own numbers? [y/n] ");            
                String stBuyTicket = keyboard.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();
                if (stBuyTicket.isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
                }
                else if (stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'y' || stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'n')
                {
                    if (stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'y')
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < userLottoLength; i++)
                        {
                            boolean checkUserLotto = false;
                            while (checkUserLotto != true)
                            {
                                System.out.print("Which number would you like to choose for number " + (i + 1) + ": ");
                                String numUserInput = keyboard.nextLine().trim();

                                int numUserInputLength = numUserInput.length();
                                boolean checkInput = true;
                                if (numUserInputLength > 2 || numUserInputLength < 1)
                                {
                                    System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again.");
                                    checkInput = false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < numUserInputLength; j++)
                                    {
                                        if (Character.isDigit(numUserInput.charAt(j)) != true)
                                        {
                                            System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again.");
                                            checkInput = false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                if (checkInput == true)
                                {
                                    int userInput = Integer.parseInt(numUserInput);
                                    if (userInput > MAX || userInput < 1)
                                    {
                                        System.out.println("Invalid Input. Try again.");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        boolean confirmSame = false;
                                        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                                        {
                                            if (userInput == userLotto[j])
                                            {
                                                System.out.println("You've already choosen this number. Choose again.");
                                                confirmSame = true;
                                            }
                                        }
                                        if (confirmSame != true)
                                        {
                                            userLotto[i] = userInput;
                                            checkUserLotto = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < userLottoLength; i++)
                        {                            
                            boolean checkLotto = false;
                            while (checkLotto != true)
                            {  
                                int numCheck = (rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1);
                                boolean confirmSame = false;                                
                                for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
                                {
                                    if (numCheck == userLotto[j])
                                    {
                                        confirmSame = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (confirmSame != true)
                                {
                                    userLotto[i] = numCheck;
                                    checkLotto = true;                                               
                                }
                            }
                        } 
                    }
                    readInput = true;
                    System.out.print("Your lotto numbers are: " + userLotto[0]);
                    for (int i = 1; i < userLottoLength; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(", " + userLotto[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.print("!");
                    System.out.println();

                    System.out.print("And the winning lotto numbers are: " + lotto[0]);
                    for (int i = 1; i < lottoLength; i++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(", " + lotto[i]);
                    }
                    System.out.print("!");
                    System.out.println();

                    Arrays.sort(lotto);
                    Arrays.sort(userLotto);

                    if (Arrays.equals(userLotto, lotto) == true)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your lotto numbers match the winning lotto numbers! \nYou win!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Your lotto numbers do not match the winning lotto numbers. \nYou lose.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
                }
            }
            readInput = false;
            while (readInput != true)
            {
                System.out.print("Would you like to buy another lotto ticket? [y/n] ");
                String stBuyTicket = keyboard.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

                if (stBuyTicket.isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
                }
                else if (stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'y' || stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'n')
                {
                    if (stBuyTicket.charAt(0) == 'y')
                    {
                        checkPlay = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        checkPlay = false;
                    }
                    readInput = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Input.");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("That's a good decision. Save your money");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The following is the part that randomizes the lotto set without repitition:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lottoLength; i++) {
                boolean checkLotto = false;
                while (checkLotto != true) {  
                    int numCheck = (rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1);
                    boolean confirmSame = false;
                    for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                        if (numCheck == lotto[j]) {
                            confirmSame = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (confirmSame != true) {
                        lotto[i] = numCheck;
                        checkLotto = true;                                               
                    }
                }
            }
```

It generates a number with `int numCheck = (rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1)` and checks that number against every inputted lotto number so far:

```
for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
    if (numCheck == lotto[j]) {
        confirmSame = true;
    }
}
```

If `numCheck` does not equal any inputted number, then `numCheck` is written to the current array spot.